# How can i store FCM push notification result to variable?

Tags: php, curl, push-notification

Here is my Code:

```
<?php
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$token = "*****";
$serverKey = "*****"; 

$title = "This is Title";
$body = "Body of the message";
$param_arr = array();
$param_arr['page_name'] = "notification";
$param_arr['id'] = "10";

$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'is_background' =>'' , 'text' => $body, 'image' => '', 'payload' => $param_arr);

$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 'data' => $notification,'priority'=>'high', 'timestamp'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

and in browser shows result:

```
{"multicast_id":5813147991035715680,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

now i need to get success or failure status from that result,
how can i get status and store to variable ?

$response gives boolean response

```
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: You've posted your secret API key to a public forum, you'll want to revoke it immediately.

Comment: It was wrong secret API Key, thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0):

curl_exec by default sends the response string to standerd output, browser in your case.

To store the result in a variable you should set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true.

I think that will work.

Don't tell me that you have tried it as well and found negative. :-)